# MySQL, function returning NULL value

Tags: mysql

I tried creating a function which should return the id of the spell which has the highest damage value. I have two types of damage dealing spells, the ones who deal damage per step and those who deal damage in one step. Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION `getSpellMaxDmgID`(`pCharID` int(11))
RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE pdmgpts int(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pdmgprstp int(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pdmgmaxspellid int(11) DEFAULT 0;

IF (SELECT MAX(`damage_points`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=pCharID)) IS NOT NULL THEN
SET pdmgpts=(SELECT MAX(`damage_points`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=pCharID));
END IF;
IF (SELECT MAX(`damage_per_step`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=pCharID)) IS NOT NULL THEN
SET pdmgprstp=(SELECT MAX(`damage_per_step`) FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`spell_id` IN( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=pCharID));
END IF;
IF pdmgpts>=pdmgprstp THEN
SET pdmgmaxspellid=(SELECT `spell_id` FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`damage_points`=pdmgpts AND `spell`.`spell_id` IN ( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=pCharID) LIMIT 1);
ELSE
SET pdmgmaxspellid=(SELECT `spell_id` FROM `spell` WHERE `spell`.`damage_per_step`=pdmgpts AND `spell`.`spell_id` IN ( SELECT `spell_id` FROM `character_spell` WHERE `character_spell`.`character_id`=pCharID) LIMIT 1);
END IF;

RETURN pdmgmaxspellid;

END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to call the function like this `SELECT getSpellMaxDmgID(8)`, the function returns me NULL value, even if it should return an integer value, giving that the character with that character ID has spells on his spell list. Can anyone see the issue here? Thanks in advance!

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `spell` (
`spell_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`spell_type_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`magicka_cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
`damage_per_step` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`damage_points` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fortify_points` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`spell_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_spell_spell_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`spell_type_id`) REFERENCES `spell_type`(`spell_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

And some data:

`INSERT INTO spell (spell_type_id, name, magicka_cost, damage_per_step) VALUES (2, 'Summon Dremora', 84, 30);
INSERT INTO spell (spell_type_id, name, magicka_cost, damage_per_step) VALUES (2, 'Summon Flame Atronach', 69, 25);
INSERT INTO spell (spell_type_id, name, magicka_cost, damage_points) VALUES (3, 'Fire Damage', 10, 30);
INSERT INTO spell (spell_type_id, name, magicka_cost, damage_points) VALUES (3, 'Frost Damage', 10, 30);
INSERT INTO spell (spell_type_id, name, magicka_cost, fortify_points) VALUES (2, 'Bound Boots', 6, 10);
INSERT INTO spell (spell_type_id, name, magicka_cost, fortify_points) VALUES (2, 'Bound Cuirass', 6, 10);`

Spell type:

```
CREATE TABLE `spell_type` (
`spell_type_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`spell_type_id`));
```

`INSERT INTO`spell_type`(`name`) VALUES ('Alteration');
INSERT INTO`spell_type`(`name`) VALUES ('Conjuration');
INSERT INTO`spell_type`(`name`) VALUES ('Destruction');
INSERT INTO`spell_type`(`name`) VALUES ('Illusion');
INSERT INTO`spell_type`(`name`) VALUES ('Mysticism');
INSERT INTO`spell_type`(`name`) VALUES ('Restoration');`

Character spell:

`CREATE TABLE`character_spell`(`
character_spell_id`int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
character_id`int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`
spell_id`int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`character_spell_id`),
    CONSTRAINT`uk_character_id_spell_id`UNIQUE (`character_id`,`spell_id`),
    CONSTRAINT`fk_character_spell_character_id`FOREIGN KEY (`character_id`) REFERENCES`character`(`character_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT`fk_character_spell_spell_id`FOREIGN KEY (`spell_id`) REFERENCES`spell`(`spell_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);`

`INSERT INTO`character_spell`(`character_id`,`spell_id`) VALUES(`character_id`, 10);
                INSERT INTO`character_spell`(`character_id`,`spell_id`) VALUES(`character_id`, 14);
                INSERT INTO`character_spell`(`character_id`,`spell_id`) VALUES(`character_id`, 18);
                INSERT INTO`character_spell`(`character_id`,`spell_id`) VALUES(`character_id`, 28);
                INSERT INTO`character_spell`(`character_id`,`spell_id`) VALUES(`character_id`, 55);
                INSERT INTO`character_spell`(`character_id`,`spell_id`) VALUES(`character_id`, 87);`

Character:

`CREATE TABLE`character`(`
character_id`int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
user_id`int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`
name`varchar(30) NOT NULL,`
sex`varchar(10) NOT NULL,`
xp`bigint NOT NULL,`
level`bigint NOT NULL,`
money`bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`character_id`),
    CONSTRAINT`uk_character_id_user_id`UNIQUE (`character_id`,`user_id`)
);`

`INSERT INTO`character`(`user_id`,`name`,`sex`,`xp`,`level`,`money`) VALUES(`7`,`Mashiela`,`Female`, 0, 1, 250);`

Comment: Provide table structure with data..

Comment: There you go, hope it helps.

Comment: `spell_type` table??

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: `character_spell` ??

Comment: Alright, there you go.

Comment: Also, I will include the character table. I won't include the user table because it is not needed.

Comment: Data for character_spell and character?

Comment: Character id should be 8 and those spell ids are different from the list I sent you though, you should try with 1 to count(spell_id).